# WordPress: add_rewrite_rule with flexible path length? (Tag filter)

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I need your help regarding WordPress URL rewrite. :o) At first, I am get this working:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(?:page/?([0-9]{1,})?/?)?$' , 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top');
```

This does some actions:

- I can enter "blog.domain/category/category-name/" and get to the
  category archive - with or without "page(d)" 
  I can also enter
  "blog.domain/category/category-name/a-tag/" (or with "page/n/") and
  get to the category archive, where the posts are filtered by an tag.

Now, I could extend this rewrite rule, f.e.:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(?:page/?([0-9]{1,})?/?)?$' , 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]+$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]', 'top');
```

This one will also works with "blog.domain/category/category-name/tag1/tag2/".

What I want to do is an pretty URL, so that users could filter the posts more and more by tags (f.e. /category/cars/racing/red/). Problem: for every new "path" (for category/cars/racing/ and category/cars/racing/red/) I need one add_rewrite_rule.

Is there any solution to reach this behavior with one single line? Maybe something like "there could be another path (as tag), but it mustn't"?